# what does maxLength="#length" means in an xml android layout file?

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-edittext

Does someone knows what the #attribute value means in this xml file?

```
<EditText
                 android:id="@+id/firmaText"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                 android:ems="8"
                 android:textColor="@color/black"
                 android:textSize="14sp" 
                 android:paddingLeft="5sp"
                 android:inputType="textPassword"
                 android:lines="1"
                 android:maxLength="#{longitud}"
                 android:text="#{pin}"/>
```

I know the meaning and use of the maxLength attribute, the problem is the value it have.

I also think is a kind of preprocessing, but, it doesnt compile...

Comment: At first search on google

Comment: May be it's for a sort of preprocessing?

Comment: I`ve already searched it on google.

Comment: It's broken syntax if it does not compile but where did you get the file?

Comment: Its a library that I`ve to include in my project

Comment: Not a public library

Answer (score 0):

Solved, it was a syntax error of the library.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

android:maxLength

Set an input filter to constrain the text length to the specified number.

Must be an integer value, such as "100".

For Example : android:maxLength="6" limits the length of the EditText to 6 characters.

This may also be a reference to a resource (in the form "@[package:]type:name") or theme attribute (in the form "?[package:][type:]name") containing a value of this type.